# How are ros_control controllers and hardware_interfaces used?

Tags: ros, ros-control, hardware-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

The doc for ros_control says [ros_control provides controller interfaces](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control). Does that mean ros_control abstracts real controllers?

- I noticed ros_control also provides software controllers? I guess these are mostly used for simulation or for cheap control in real life, is that right?
- Now, are the controllers interfaces (i.e. controllers abstractions) used both in case of real hardware drivers and in case of ros_control emulated controllers?

Thanks,

Antoine.

PS: please note that I have read all the doc I could find for ros_control (both in the wiki or on github).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191289/how-are-ros_control-controllers-and-hardware_interfaces-used?/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-08-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2015-01-23**:
Is this question still valid or can it be closed?. Since it was asked many interactions have taken place in the robot control SIG.

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2015-01-23**:
You are right, this question is now answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All answers to this question can be found in [Adolfo Rodriguez's RosCon 2014 lecture](http://roscon.ros.org/2014/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ros_control_an_overview.pdf)

Regards,

Antoine.

---

Originally posted by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) with karma: 955 on 2015-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0